# Clear history webview on flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview, webview-flutter

How to clear history for android on [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)?

Actually I already used [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) because this plugin provide clear history method using `controller.android.clearHistory()` but I am facing issue with the `onLoadStop` for IOS. `onLoadStop` only called once meanwhile for android it works properly so I decided to change the webview package to [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter).